# using m2eclipse, how could I pass system property

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I am new in using m2eclipse. I have a maven project imported into Eclipse and need to configure run as maven project. The maven command need to pass a system property:

```
mvn -Dargline="-MyProperty=PropertyValue" clean install
```

How could I set the "run configration..." to pass the argument? I tried many times and still cannot get through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on project, Run As > Maven Build...

Then click on the table at the bottom, click Add..., set argLine as parameter name, -DMyProperty=PropertyValue  as parameter value

Comment: Thank you Fred. I should ask the question earlier so it would save me time:)